# Returning Mat object from native code to java in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I have an OpenCV Android app. Most of its code is in Java but I have
one function that is in C.
The function gets a Mat object and returns a new one.

My question is how do I return a Mat from the native code to Java?
Couldn't find any example of that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Today I had to return a Mat from native code. I started with "Tutorial 2 Advanced - 2. Mix Java+Native OpenCV" it already passes two Mat (Images captured from camera) objects to the native code.
But I wanted to return extracted feature, thus I added `jlong addrDescriptor` to the signature:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial4_Sample4View_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrDescriptor)
{
    Mat* pMatGr=(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat* pMatRgb=(Mat*)addrRgba;
    Mat* pMatDesc=(Mat*)addrDescriptor;
    vector<KeyPoint> v;

    //OrbFeatureDetector detector(50);
    OrbFeatureDetector detector;
    OrbDescriptorExtractor  extractor;
    detector.detect(*pMatGr, v);
    extractor.compute( *pMatGr, v, *pMatDesc );
    circle(*pMatRgb, Point(100,100), 10, Scalar(5,128,255,255));
    for( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
        circle(*pMatRgb, Point(v[i].pt.x, v[i].pt.y), 10, Scalar(255,128,0,255));
    }
    }
}
```

In the java part I added the Mat

```
private Mat descriptor;
descriptor = new Mat();
```

The method `getNativeObjAddr()` does the trick. The Mat is allocated in java and its address is passed to the native code, thus there isn't any explicit returning.

```
FindFeatures(mGraySubmat.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), descriptor.getNativeObjAddr());
Log.i("desc:"  , descriptor.dump());
```

The Mat was filled with the required data and is directly accessible in the java code after the JNI invokation returns.

Somwhere else in the code the Mat is released:

```
if ( descriptor != null) 
  descriptor.release();
descriptor = null;
```

Comment: Hi stacker, changed my native code to this: Mat* image=(Mat*)addrDescriptor;
 Mat processing(*image.size(), CV_8UC3);
 cv::medianBlur(*image, processing, 5); Now i get the following error message : jni/objDetector.cpp:23: error: request for member 'size' in 'image', which is of non-class type 'cv::Mat*

Comment: @SaqibRazaq the signature is `void medianBlur(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, int ksize)` you need to invoke it with a reference to processing. try `&processing`. Or define it as `Mat& processing(image.size(), CV_8UC3);`

Comment: @SaqibRazaq If you want to return `Mat &dst`, then you should declare it in your java code and add it to the invocation of JNI method the same way you added `image`.

Comment: @stacker what do you mean by `Somwhere else in the code the Mat is released:`

Comment: @RomanticElectron that the code (last 3 lines of the post) should be invoked to release memory after the work is done.

Answer (score 7):

in C++

```
jlong funC(){
Mat *mat = new Mat();
//...
return (jlong)mat;
}
```

in java:

```
long = addr;// addr is return from c method funC()
Mat mat = new Mat(addr);
```

Attention: You must new Mat() in C,if you code is : Mat mat();mat object memory will be collect when funC() end.