# Return detected plate number

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I done my app based on this blog:
[Tracking pin pong ball](http://projectproto.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/OpenCV)

despite of my program tracks squares/rectangles as it has to find and extract the plate number from cyclist back. Question is how I can pass the picture (detected and cropped number) back to android code to pass it to the tesseract? Any help would be appreciated. Please be lenient I am new in this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for the opencv sample called faceview.java.

you will get an array with the raw image data for you to do with as you wish

```
 onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera)
```

...forgive me if i don't understand the exact question, but let me know and i can clarify

Comment: Hello. Question in pretty much similar to :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935618/returning-mat-object-from-native-code-to-java-in-opencv)
but i do not quite understand the solution

Comment: The difference is i want to get cropped picture back from native function to android code to pass it then to tesseract OCR

Comment: are you using opencv from native c app or from java app?

Comment: i've only used JavaCV from android, and i see you didn't post any code sample, but i imagine that at some point you are creating an image using cvCreateImage, and filling it with pixels, cropping, thresholding etc.  you can then use the getByteBuffer() method to get a pointer to the image pixels that you can manipulate in code, turn into an android bitmap like (mMyBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(myImgOpenCv.getByteBuffer()); ) and then perhapse point tesseract to the bitmap or pixel array?