# Pass Mat to JNI function - OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass a `Mat` object through a JNI function using a `jlong` but I get this exception at runtime:

```
(__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+276)
(__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())+8)
(std::terminate()+20)
(__cxa_throw+148)
(cv::error(cv::Exception const&)+80)
(cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)+18)
(cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&)+122)
(cv::_InputArray::getMat(int) const+252)
(cv::split(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)+20)
(cv::split(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)+28)
(cv::xphoto::balanceWhite(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int, float, float, float, float)+54)
(Java_com_myapp_camera_CameraManager_simpleWhiteBalance+18)
```

The native function is defined like this

```
public native static void simpleWhiteBalance(Mat source, Mat dest);
```

and it's implemented in the following way

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/xphoto.hpp"
#include "simple_color_balance.cpp"
#include "com_myapp_camera_CameraManager.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myapp_camera_CameraManager_simpleWhiteBalance
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong in, jlong out) {

     cv::Mat& inMat = *(cv::Mat*)in;
     cv::Mat& outMat = *(cv::Mat*)out;

    cv::xphoto::balanceWhite(inMat, outMat, cv::xphoto::WHITE_BALANCE_SIMPLE);
}
```

I am new to C++, what does the exception mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jlong` is not mapping an object but `long` (object is mapped as `jobject`) and Java instance of `Mat` is completely different from instance of `cv::Mat` and cannot be casted this way. The usual way here is to use `long`s in Java as approximation of pointers in C++ and cast it in the way you use.

Also, this is not an exception but a crash caused by uncaught exception. To get the exception, you would need to use try - catch in your C++ code. C++ exceptions are incompatible with Java exceptions and so you cannot throw in C++ and catch it in Java or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, solved passing a long object through the Mat.getNativeObjAddress()

Comment: ok, how to convert `jlong` to cv::Mat ?

Answer (score -1):

```
cv::Mat *inMat = (cv::Mat*)in;
cv::Mat *outMat = (cv::Mat*)out;
```

and please pass *pointer* instead of references. see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935618/returning-mat-object-from-native-code-to-java-in-opencv)

Comment: sorry，I guess he know what I mean,  he must convert mat pointer to jlong

Comment: Stupid question - little C++ experience - why pass a pointer rather than a reference?