# return three Mat frames from JNI

Tags: java, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i developing Cam-shift in android with opencv i have c++ code wants to implement it in android ndk but i have did quite of bit ,first i send my three Mat object to natives sides like this

```
OpencvClass.humanDetection(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(),frame.getNativeObjAddr(),hsv.getNativeObjAddr());
```

on Native side i have read my frames like this

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_abr_mypl5_OpencvClass_humanDetection
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba,addrFrame,addrHsv){
   Mat& rgba = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
   Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrFrame;
   Mat& HSV = *(Mat*)addrHsv;


    // here i have implement my code 

    //now i want to return  back this three frames in java side 


  }
```

**at the end i want to return back my three frames to java side how would i do that** i have search a lot but didnt find a good solution , Is there anyone who can help me for this question ????

Comment: I don't see any need to return the `Mat`s, since you're passing them by-address. Any changes you make to the `Mat`s in native code should be reflected on the Java side (as long as you don't make copies somewhere before the modification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass objects as pointers, you don't need to return it to get changes. In this case you have direct access to object location inside memory and every changes will be applyed immediately.

Take look at [additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053200/3926506) about your question.

Comment: in this example he passed three objects but if we want to pass more than three , can we pass it throw array of objects ?? if yes how??

Comment: You can pass pointers via `long[]` from Java. At JNI side this argument will be `jlongArray`

Comment: Thanks for your help